# does multiple upload follow the same order of uploading in which we select the images?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

i am using HTML5 multiple upload feature.

```
<input name='upload[]' type=file multiple="multiple" id="profileImages" />
```

its working perfect. Now I have one query

**does multiple uploading follow any order while uploading images?**

suppose I have 5 images

```
a.png
b.png
c.png
d.png
e.png
```

now while uploading images if I select images in below order

```
a.png, 
b.png,
e.png,
d.png,
c.png
```

**does these images would be uploaded in the same order I select?**

means `$_FILES['upload']['name']` array will have (using **PHP** )

```
[0] =>'a.png',
[1] =>'b.png',
[2] =>'e.png',
[3] =>'d.png',
[4] = >'c.png'
```

or it depends upon **filesize** or **browser** or **any other factor/attribute** ?

---

#### sidenote

further i m storing these images individually in  **profile_image_table**

```
id(pk ) | profile_id | image_name
```

answer of above question will make my work easy because if multiple image upload in the order we select then it would be easier to choose one image for main profile image ( using `MIN(id)` or `MAX(id)` ) of given `profile_id`.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the answer to this will be "it depends on the browser", because it will be generally assumed that if you are using a multiple upload input that the order would be insignificant, because you are uploading a collection of files with the same control. If you want to guarantee ordering, have multiple input elements which handle a single file each, and name them `upload[0]`, `upload[1]` etc. I suspect you will find that most browsers will deliver the files in the order they were selected, but this should not be relied upon because you were not explicit.

Comment: @DaveRandom then there is no mean of `multiple` feature. that is old method as we don't know how many picture user wants to upload.

Comment: does multiple uploading follow any order while uploading images? - Sorting/Ordering - it depends how you sort images in 'browse dialog'

Comment: @DaveRandom I find that Chrome always upload in reverse order. means the file you choose last will be uploaded first.

Comment: @Pēteris does it really follow?

Comment: @diEcho I think you're possibly over-thinking this and/or trying to second guess the user on the decision. I get where you're coming from with the desire to do this in one operation, but I think it would be more user friendly to let the user upload the files, identify and file them appropriately, then display them back to the user afterwards and let them choose which file they want as a profile pic - it feels like a more intuitive user experience to me.

Comment: @DaveRandom I am completely agree with you. i stuck in this situation because  client demands this at the end of the project :(. so either i have to add one single file upload button only for profile pic. or i thought that  we  can get first/last image from multiple upload button.

Comment: @diEcho sort by works in chrome, but in firefox it selects order by how they are checked.. Filename: "1.txt" "b.txt" "bb.txt" "c.txt" "e.txt"  - in ff you can mix order..

Comment: @diEcho Well I think your only option is *<shudder>* user agent sniffing. You will need to catalogue how various browser/OS combinations behave, and handle as appropriate. I would definitely take the time to build in the code to handle it with the two-pass approach now though - the client *will* get complaints about it and they *will* come back to you and ask you to change it - and when they do you can do nothing for 2 weeks, put the code live and charge them a fortune for the changes ;-)

Comment: @diEcho this is a very old post, but in Chrome 110.0.5481.180 I confirmed the order of the File array passed to the change() event is not dependent on filename - in fact it seems random.  So you definitely cannot count on any deterministic ordering even for this one browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 has *nothing* to do with file uploads where the server is concerned. Period. There is no reliable "order." As the comments have noted, the actual order resulting from the new HTML5 `multiple` fields can vary from browser to browser. To understand why, we need to look at what happens when a user-agent (browser) submits a form with multiple file fields to a PHP server.

When you upload multiple files from an HTML form your browser is doing a couple of things automatically for you:

1. Sending a `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header to inform the remote HTTP server that it's sending several discrete "blocks" of information within the context of this single request.
2. Building a raw HTTP message that conforms to the HTTP specification to transport your files using the HTTP protocol.

The raw HTTP message will look something like this:

```
POST /somePath HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: my-browser-v0.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------

------------------------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]" filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

these were the contents of file1.txt
------------------------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="file2.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

these were the contents of file2.txt
```

It's completely up to the browser in which order it places the data from your form. User-Agent sniffing is not really a viable option to determine the ordering. Instead, if the order of the fields is that important (pointless idea, but whatever), you should use a form in which there are a finite number of possible file fields and name them individually. This way you can access the files by their field names in the `$_FILES` array. After all, you aren't required to use the new HTML5 feature just because it exists:

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input name='file1' type=file>
  <input name='file2' type=file>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

And in your PHP file access the fields directly by their names. You'll know which form field name was first because you coded the HTML that way:

```
<?php
$_FILES['file1'];
$_FILES['file2'];
```

---

Perhaps a better solution in your case would be to simply have one file field that is named directly (so you always know it's the primary field) and then add the multi-select field for users to add further files.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, no, it depends on the browser and the server and the order they wish to do it.

For a file to get from a web page to PHP it takes three steps.

1. Browser takes the files and puts them nicely in a post to the Apache (or other) and then it transmits everything.
2. The browser will see the incoming data, will keep the headers, some of them it will pass to PHP but not all and for the files it will write them to /tmp and then send the info of where they are located to PHP.

In bought the above cases order can change. 
Technically they should go in the same order, but not a must.
In case of bulk uploads via Flash or any other multi-selection option they will go in reverse, but deppendinging on wo knows what some files might be taken out of their order and placed first or last.

**Best way to ensure they go in the same order is to have different names for all file field instead of using an array.**

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem when using the Laravel media-library package.

When I wanted to upload multiple files, this was a problem because a different order was used compared to the one I chose when saving in the database.

anyway,

In fact, we sometimes make mistakes by thinking complex. As a solution I did input repeater.

like a

```
<input name='upload[]' type='file'/>
<input name='upload[]' type='file'/>
<input name='upload[]' type='file'/>
```

In this way, we can post each uploaded file in order. And yes we can't select multiple but I couldn't find any other solution.

I think it wasn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, all the files you upload will get arranged according to the filename. I have tested it.