# Images upload in the wrong order

Tags: php, sql

I am aware it's an old script (an old way of doing things). The script works, however, the images do not upload in the right order. I am not exactly sure but it looks to me they upload from last to first instead of from first to last. What makes it do that?

```
if (count($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']))
{
    $ipval = ipval();
    $uploaderror = 0;
    $uploadcount = 0;
    $errorMessages = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'] as $k=>$tmpfile)
}
if ($tmpfile)
{
    $thisfile = array("name"=>$_FILES['pic']['name'][$k],
    "tmp_name"=>$_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'][$k],
    "size"=>$_FILES['pic']['size'][$k],
    "type"=>$_FILES['pic']['type'][$k],
    "error"=>$_FILES['pic']['error'][$k]);
    if ($_FILES['pic']['size'][$k] > $pic_maxsize*1000)
    {
        $errorMessages[] = $thisfile['name'] . " - " . $lang['ERROR_UPLOAD_PIC_TOO_BIG'];
        $uploaderror++;
    }
    elseif (!isValidImage($thisfile))
    {
        $errorMessages[] = $thisfile['name'] . " - " . $lang['ERROR_UPLOAD_PIC_BAD_FILETYPE'];
        $uploaderror++;
    }
    else
    {
        $newfile = SaveUploadFile($thisfile, "{$path_escape}{$datadir['adpics']}", TRUE, $images_max_width, $images_max_height);
        if($newfile)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $t_adpics
            SET adid = $adid,
            picfile = '$newfile'";
            mysql_query($sql);
            if (mysql_error())
            {

                ...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108468/does-multiple-upload-follow-the-same-order-of-uploading-in-which-we-select-the-i

Comment: No, not quite. I tried that. It seems like they are still reversed once uploaded. It seems like they upload from last to first, even when I assign #'s to them i.e. $_FILES['pic']['1']  ||  $_FILES['pic']['2'] etc.

Answer (score 0):

If by "order" you mean the order that you selected the images in a multiple file input, you cannot rely on that order being consistent on the back end. It varies by browser and server: [does multiple upload follow the same order of uploading in which we select the images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108468/does-multiple-upload-follow-the-same-order-of-uploading-in-which-we-select-the-i)

If you are always seeing the order reversed, perhaps you need to change some code in the script that serves them up (`ASC` instead of `DESC`).

One way you could keep the order consistent is by sending another variable to the server on upload that contains an array of the file names in order, then base your `INSERT` order off of that array, not the order of the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can "send another variable to the server on upload that contains an array of the file names in order" ? Not sure I know exactly how to do that.